# Enlarge on mobile view

Tags: css, html-table, bootstrap-4

How to fit table on mobile view?

I want:
[image]

---

> But it is as:

[image]

---

My codes:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h2>Text:</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text text text text text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-danger float-left">Select</a><a href="" class="btn btn-success float-right">Go Ahead</a>
</div>
```

---

How to fit table on mobile view?
The result for the above codes is not readable properly, we have to zoom it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change from `<div class="container">` to `<div class="container-fluid">`

And add meta `viewport` for your page.

```
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Here is result with container-fluid

[image]

If you don't want to use `container-fluid`, you can setup in media query max width 767px, remove max-width values and set margin to 0 for `container` class

[image]

Comment: In `container-fluid` the width goes full, good. But the size doesn't increase. See my Required Image!